# React Native (0.59.10) — How do I remove `useNativeDriver` when running tests (but not in the actual app)

Tags: react-native, animation, jestjs, native, react-native-elements

I am building a project with React Native (version 0.59.10). Whenever I run my tests (using Jest) I get this warning:

```
    console.warn node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper.js:248
      Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing. Falling back to JS-based animation. To resolve this, add `RCTAnimation` module to this app, or remove `useNativeDriver`. More info: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11094#issuecomment-263240420
```

This seems to be due to the use of `Animated` in `TouchableOpacity` which is in turn used by `Button` from 'react-native-elements'.

Looking into my project with Xcode I can see that the `RCNativeAnimation` project is there:

[image: screen snap from Xcode showing RCNativeAnimation exists]

I checked the referenced link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11094#issuecomment-263240420 but that is ages old and refers to very old versions of both React Native and Xcode.

I am guessing this warning is just related to the native `RCNativeAnimation` module not being accessible from the tests but I am at a loss as to how to 'remove `useNativeDriver`' within the test context.  Obviously in the real app I want to ensure I am using the native animation libraries, but in the unit tests I don't care.

What is the recommended way to eliminate this warning?

Answer (score 3):

change the jest.mock to:

```
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper');
```

Answer (score 1):

add `jest.mock('NativeAnimatedHelper');` to your test file

Comment: When I tried adding this line to my test file, I got an error that says `Cannot find module 'NativeAnimatedHelper' from 'App-test.tsx'`. This is after following the v4 docs on a v0.61.1 RN app where I installed `react-navigation`, `react-native-gesture-handler`, and `react-navigation-stack`, and then ran `pod install` in my `ios` directory.